# Terraform: assume_role block is breaking the deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, terraform

I have two separate AWS accounts. I want to create a replica of the Account1[A1] infrastructure in Account[A2] using Terraform. When I create (eg) a blog instance , I want to take an Elastic IP and register it with a new R53 record in R53 service of the first account.

I fetch the existing blog AMI id to use in order to launch EC2 instances, with a data resource . eg...

```
data "aws_ami" "blog-ami-source" {
  owners = ["self"] # The account ID
  filter {
    name = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["Blog"]
  }
  most_recent = true
}
```

For this example blog, I create an Elastic IP resource to attach to. Then I want to create an R53 record with this IP in A1's R53 , something like `blog-terra.example.com` .

For this to happen I read the docs [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/) & [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) and I have created a role in the first account and attached an inline policy in the Terraform user in the second account. So I have this code

```
### The AWS provider configuration ###
provider "aws" {
  # Grab the credentials dynamically from the credentials file
  # Windows setup
  shared_credentials_file  = "C:\\Users\\USER\\.aws\\credentials"
  # Linux setup
  //  shared_credentials_file  = "$HOME/.aws/credentials"

  profile = "TF_User" # the terraform user applies only to the 2nd account

  region  = "${var.aws_region}"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id_1}:role/${var.R53_cross_account_role_name}"
    session_name = "SESSION_for_${var.R53_cross_account_role_name}"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "account_1_provider"
  shared_credentials_file  = "C:\\Users\\USER\\.aws\\credentials"
  profile = "Generic_User" # the Generic user applies only to the 1st account
  region  = "${var.aws_region}"
}
```

also the code that creates the R53 records is this

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  provider = "aws.account_1_provider"
  name = "example.com." # Notice the dot!!!
  private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "Blog_route" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id}"
  name = "blog-terra.${data.aws_route53_zone.main.name}"
  type = "A"
  ttl = "300"
  records = ["${aws_eip.Blog_EIP.public_ip}"]
```

When I `terraform plan` it, I get this errors:

```
* data.aws_acm_certificate.elb-cert: Error describing certificates: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT-ID:assumed-role/Access_to_R53_for_Terraform_user
/SESSION_for_Access_to_R53_for_Terraform_user is not authorized to perform: acm:ListCertificates
        status code: 400, request id: 61f4fb62-fa77-11e6-a50d-95488550532b
* data.aws_ami.blog-ami-source: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
        status code: 403, request id: 766558dd-bf7c-4c55-95de-104a556a4b5a
```

It seems that the role to access the first account immediately applies and the rest of the operation breaks.

However if isolate the necessary code to create the R53 records with hardcoded IPs, the assumed role works fine and the records are created perfectly.

Do I do something wrong in the declaration of the assumed role?